# DIV not aligned properly

Tags: html, css, alignment

Here's my page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKp9H.png

I don't know why it's not aligned... I'm newbie in `html` and `CSS`.

Here's my code:

```css
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#logo {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

#nav {
  min-height: 640px;
  width: 130px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  float: left;
}

#content {
  min-width: 687px;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
}

#ad {
  float: left;
  width: 122px;
  min-height: 620px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}

#footer {
  clear: both;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

LINK TO [PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/6BYktPqV).

I need this for my school and I can't solve this problem.
I've been trying for past few hours to get it to work, I tried to google for fix but they don't seem to work or I'm just too dumb.

PS: Sorry for my english and my "skills" in `html`.

Comment: which `div` are you talking about?

Comment: zgood check link to photo on imgur, I'm newbie but container seems to be only one working... I want divs in center to be centered

Comment: `#content { /* float: left;*/ margin: auto; display: block; }` Taking a stab in the dark here so if I hit anything vital, just keep calm and apply pressure. Difficult to know which elements you are referring to if we have no markup for reference, and unfortunately an image on imgur has no source code to inspect. If that doesn't work, "just use `flex`" (hot-fix to all alignment issues, ever -> *disclaimer: clearly a joke, don't take that claim too seriously, please, thanks!*)

Comment: then you should try and set `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` like you did on the `#container` div - which they need to have a width set to center

Comment: UncaughtTypeError Can you please tell me wher to put this and so on? I also provided link to PASTEBIN if you want to see whole code. Here's what I want it too lok like: (Paint made) https://imgur.com/a/B7Iw9

Comment: Yea, it's most likely one of the containing elements that needs a `float` removed in favour of block-type element and margin alignment

Comment: Just add it (the html) to the Code Snippet you already have there.

Comment: I tried giving margin-left and right to all div's but it wasn't working :/... IDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to put all content inside the container. "nav", "content" and so on are currently not inside the container as the container is closed before "nav" starts. To put everything inside the container you have to remove the `</DIV>`-tag before `<DIV ID="nav">`. This also fixes the problem with the stray `</DIV>`-tag at the end. Hope this helps.

Comment: Man! You are a god! I can't believe that it was that simple! I would give you rep+ but can't give any with rep below 15. Thanks to all who helped! <3           PS: If anyone knows how to end this thread please say how.

Comment: Glad i could help. You can accept my answer. That basically marks the answer you found most helpful.